# Platform-agnostic way to monitor filesystem events

Tags: c++, linux, macos, inotify, kqueue

I'm currently developing a C++ application which should monitor the file system to reindex a set of files when they change. I am currently using Linux' inotify system, but would like the application to be as broadly portable to other systems as possible.

Do you know of high-level, portable filesystem monitoring libraries, which would work at least on Linux and Mac OSX? (and have C or C++ bindings?)

Comment: Maybe `boost::filesystem`? I didn't really check for this specific functionality.

Comment: @C.R. thanks, but it looks like boost::filesystem only helps for common filesystem manipulations (manipulate paths, list directories, ...) It doesn't seem to monitor events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) with [QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qfilesystemwatcher.html)

> **QFileSystemWatcher Class**
>
> The QFileSystemWatcher class provides an interface for monitoring files and directories for modifications. [More...](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qfilesystemwatcher.html#details)

Comment: Thanks. I'm usually not a big fan of Qt, but I'll try it.